# Code formating in LaTeX

Tags: algorithms

Any suggestions on how to achieve a look for a code as seen in the picture?

Maybe with "listings" or do I need to do it manualy?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd strongly recommend taking a look at the `algorithmic` package. `listings` is a package to print/import **code**. Text algorithms can easily be typeset with `algorithmic` and friends.

Comment: Ah yes, this is what I was looking for! Thank you :)

Comment: that's definately achieved with `algorithmic`. an alternative is `minted`.